# will the Dynamically allocated memory be Automatically released,when the program ends

Tags: c++

here is the example:

```
int *p=new int;
system("Pause");
return 0;
```

If we don't execute the delete p operation,will the memory be automatically released,when the program runs over.

Comment: just for your information: don't use system("pause");

Answer (score 0):

This depends on which operating system you are using. Both Linux and Windows will clean up all resources use by a process when the process terminates.